# WPF Rectangle movement with Animation

Tags: wpf

I have a requirement of moving dynamically created rectangles dynamically.

I am almost done with my implementation, and if I write the code below for each of the rectangle dynamically, I am able to achieve the desired result.

The code below moves the desired rectangle by 50 pixels on X Axis.

```
TranslateTransform translateTransform1 = new TranslateTransform(50, 0); aRectangle.RenderTransform = translateTransform1;
```

The problem is I want this to be animated. The code below is written to have the same rectanle moved with animation, but gives entirelly different result all together. Any help will be much appreciated. I want it to manage through code as my rectangles are going to be dynamic.

```
TranslateTransform translateTransform1 = new TranslateTransform(50, 0);
Duration duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0));
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(30, duration);
translateTransform1.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim);
aRectangle.RenderTransform = translateTransform1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Duration duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0));
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(30, duration);
aRectangle.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
aRectangle.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim);
```

Comment: Where do I specify that I would like to move the rectangle on X axis by 50 pixels?

Comment: Through `aRectangle.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim);` you specify which property to animate and in `DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(30, duration);` one determines where to stop. So change the 30 to 50 and it will move 50 pixels on the x-Axsis. If you want to animate two or more properties you have to use the `Storyboard`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx